# How to get Audio Data form Oboe at fixed time intervals

Tags: android, oboe

I am working on synchronizing audio streams from different audio devices Is there a way to get audio data burst on android after fixed time intervals. for example after every 40 ms

Answer (score 3):

You can not get data based on time in Oboe, but you can define the sampling rate and data callback rate that will give you frames in almost constant time.

for example

**Results at 20 ms**

setSampleRate = 48000

setFramesPerDataCallback 960 (20ms)

fluctuate between (19 ms - 21ms)

**Results at 40 ms**

setSampleRate = 48000

setFramesPerDataCallback 1920 (40ms)

fluctuate between (39 ms - 41 ms)

Comment: Note.
At 10 ms e.g setFramesPerDataCallback 480(10ms) the timings vary a lot